# uiGrid with uiGridCellNav screen jumps on click and focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, angular-ui-grid

I have a uiGrid that uses ui-grid-cellNav which supplies single click to edit field.  If there is space at the top of the screen such that the grid is not at the top, clicking will cause the page to jump to the top. Furthermore, any buttons that are above the grid stop responding to clicks for the first click after this happens.
To see the behavior, open the PLNKR and just single click in the first cell marked '1'.  The screen will jump scroll such that the grid is at the top of the screen. Now scroll the screen so you can see the Cancel button and click it. The screen will jump back down to the grid. Scroll up again and click Cancel and now the button will work.

Here is a plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/OVNUeaGqTAoJqdZvqmQ8?p=preview

I've deduced that that rowHeight bigger than the default in the gridOptions is the cause.

```
rowHeight: 87
```

If you comment out the rowHeight option this does not happen. I've been debugging the uiGridCellNav code and this seems to be caused by something in the focus.byElement function but that is as far as I have gotten.

Comment: Actually you need to click the "Owner"  column in order to get the Cancel button behavior to stop working.  Clicking the non-editable field just causes the page jump. Also note that it seems to be related to being in edit mode on one row, and then clicking another row.

Answer (score 0):

Any grid height that prevents the page from scrolling will solve this issue

```
.ccl-ui-grid {
  height: 350px !important; //random height that skips page scroll
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I have edited your plunker with some random height and thus the issue solved https://plnkr.co/edit/VWR0qeVvmbmnQUaNpudD?p=preview